# How to setup out of office message for hibrid office environment using powershell?

Tags: powershell, microsoft-office-365, exchange-2013, exchange-hybrid

Im searching a way to set **"Out of office"** message for a user who is in office 365/exchange hybrid environment via powershell. We have a [exchange hybrid environment](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj200581(v=exchg.150).aspx). (some users are in onpremis exchange and some users are office 365. )

For on premise users we set **"out of office"** message using below powershell command

```
Set-MailboxAutoReplyConfiguration -Identity xyz -AutoReplyState Scheduled –StartTime (get-date) -EndTime (get-date).addyears(1) -InternalMessage "Dear,-ExternalMessage "Dear"
```

But this wont work for office 365 user.

```
The operation couldn't be performed because object 'xyz' couldn't be found on 'domaincontroller"
```

Any possibility to set **office 365 user** "Out of office" message via **powershell/emc** ?

According to my  research i found that in **exchange hybrid environment** commands are changed such as `new-mailbox` becomes `new-remotemailbox`. Like wise what would be the command for `Set-MailboxAutoReplyConfiguration` in office 365 ?

I could find only below compatible commands.

[image]

Comment: Is there an On-premise object for Office 365 mailbox?
If this mailbox is created in Office 365, we need to use New-RemoteMailbox to create On-premise object for those mailbox first, then On-premise user can view this object in GAL.

Comment: mail box was first created in On-premise and then migrated to office 365.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [connect to Exchange online powershell](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/exchange/exchange-online/connect-to-exchange-online-powershell/connect-to-exchange-online-powershell?view=exchange-ps) and run "Set-MailboxAutoReplyConfiguration" cmdlet for O365 users.